# Is it possible to make blurs that have an angle?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I try to make a light source a little blurry. In the compositor I use the blur filter, but that results in vertical or horizontal blurs (changing x and y values). Is it possible to make the blurs that have an angle? This image as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a dedicated [*Glare* node](http://blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/filter/glare.html) designed for creating lensflares:

[image]

I don't think it can produce diverging streaks quite like in your example, but perhaps it can come close enough?